# CSS white-space smooth transition using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a CSS transition duration appear smoother after it's changed via jQuery so that when clicking the description text, the white-space transitions to normal (open the demo and click the description text to see what I mean). I've had a long look at a load of other posts but nothing actually seems to solve this one.

Currently I've only managed to get it to apply the CSS correctly, but not animate it as I would like. I've tried:

```
$('.flex-text.description').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({whiteSpace: 'normal'});

});
```

At first I thought whiteSpace should be ['white-space'], or 'white-space', and other combinations, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know why this isn't working, and how to get it working? I'd like it to take about 500ms or so to transition completely. Thanks for any help here - the main code is below:

```js
$('.flex-text.description').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('white-space-normal', 500);
});
```

```css
/* Customisations */
/* Interaction */
.white-space-normal {
    white-space: normal !important;
    transition: all 0.4s ease; /* not working */
}
/* Buttons */
.flex-item .flex-btn-2 { background-color: #286090 !important }
/* Shop */
.shopPageListingContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex-item form {
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Generic Structure */
.sad-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    width: 23.5%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) { margin-left: 2% }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(n+5) { margin-top: 2% }
.flex-item-image-link { width: 100% }
.flex-item img {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.flex-item, .flex-text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
     position:relative;
    font-family: arial; /* perhaps remove */
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-text-content {
    padding: 10px;
    /* for ellipsis */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-item .flex-text.header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
}
.flex-item .flex-text.header a { color: #000 }
.flex-item .flex-text.price {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: grey;
}
.flex-item .flex-text.description {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-height: 6em; /* limits to 3 lines of text */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* ellipsis below: */
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px; /* solves the white-space nowrap width pushout problem */
}
.flex-item .flex-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
}
.flex-item .flex-btn:hover { opacity: 0.7 }
.flex-item ul { text-align: left }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) { margin-left: 3% }
    .flex-item { width: 48.5% }
    .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(even)) { margin-left: 0 }
    .flex-item:nth-of-type(n+3) { margin-top: 3% }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href=""><img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/" style="background-image:url(https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/219568.jpg)"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
        <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="">Caramel Shortbread Bites</a></h2>
        <span class="flex-text price">£1.20</span>
        <span class="flex-text description" style="">description token should go here description token should go here description token should go here description token should go here</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="Buy" class="flex-btn">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't animate `white-space`, there is not any values to animate. You could set height to the description and then animate the height on click. You would need to get the height of the description at start, then set height to 1 line, and animate to full height you got from the start on click. Might need to add a class for transition after initial 1 line height is set (so we don't animate the initial height set)

Comment: can you only animate values? The only problem with animating the height is that the height is different for each window as there's different amount of texts, and I can't seem to animate an auto height - mind you, max height may work

Comment: You would need to calculate height on load and on resize so you always have the correct height

Comment: thanks - I can get it to animate smoothly to the height when clicking on the text, but not animate smoothly back. I've made a CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRNwGq

Comment: This is the part where I said you need to add a class for transition after setting initial height. I haven't even looked at the code but I saw what was happening and it is for sure because you only have one class and that class has the transition so when you remove that class, the transition is also removed so you get no animation on the way back

Comment: It will be harder to make this look perfectly smooth because you are reducing the text. I would suggest you bind to transition-end when animating back and add class for the ellipsis after the height animation is over

Comment: nice ideas, thanks - I'll try that

Comment: Make sure to unbind transition end right after use. So yes, there will be a bind and unbind every time this is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a smoother transition, you could change the max-height property, from 2 to 6 for example.

Change these 2 css classes:

```
.white-space-normal {
    white-space: normal !important;
    transition: all 0.4s ease; /* not working -> now working */
    max-height: 6em !important;
}

.flex-item .flex-text.description {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-height: 6em; /* limits to 3 lines of text */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* ellipsis below: */
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px; /* solves the white-space nowrap width pushout problem */
    max-height: 2em;
}
```

Note that the toggleClass now make a transition of max-height property from 2em to 6em.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGZyqP

**--EDIT--**

To do the transition on collapse text, then you can do it with javascript setTimeout() function.

The css classes would be like that:

```
.flex-item .flex-text.description {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* ellipsis below: */
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px; /* solves the white-space nowrap width pushout problem */
    height: 2em;
    transition: height 1s ease;
}

.white-space-normal {
    padding-top: 20px;
    white-space: normal !important;
    height: 6em !important;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

And the javascript code would be like that:

```
$('.flex-text.description, .white-space-normal').click(function() {
    $el = $(".description");

    if ($el.hasClass("white-space-normal")) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $el.removeClass("white-space-normal");
        }, 500);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $el.addClass("white-space-normal");
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

New Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REvmxR

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't transition smoothly when clicking the description again to revert to how it was previously

Comment: I edited the answer and now it does the transition smoothly when clicking the transition again